# Error in sending Raw data with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have to send a request to an API. The reques should contain some data along with 4 header parameters. Teh Raw data that I want to send is the $raw_data.

The Error is  : Internal Server Error

My Code is as follows :

```
<?php


function CurlSendPostRequest($url,$request="")
    {


$raw_data='{
"job_id": null,
"collectionOnDelivery": false,
"invoice": null,
"collectionDate": "2015-01-30T09:00:00",
"consolidate": false,
"consignment": [{
"consignmentNumber": null,
"consignmentRef": null,
"parcels": [],
"collectionDetails": {
"contactDetails": {
"contactName": "My Contact",
"telephone": "0121 500 2500"
},
"address": {
"organisation": "GeoPostUK Ltd",
"countryCode": "GB",
"postcode": "B66 1BY",
"street": "Roebuck Lane",
"locality": "Smethwick",
"town": "Birmingham",
"county": "West Midlands"
}
},
"deliveryDetails": {
"contactDetails": {
"contactName": "My Contact",
"telephone": "0121 500 2500"
},
"address": {
"organisation": "GeoPostUK Ltd",
"countryCode": "GB",
"postcode": "B66 1BY",
"street": "Roebuck Lane",
"locality": "Smethwick",
"town": "Birmingham",
"county": "West Midlands"
},
"notificationDetails": {
"email": "my.email@geopostuk.com",
"mobile": "07921000001"
}
},
"networkCode": "2^12",
"numberOfParcels": 1,
"totalWeight": 5,
"shippingRef1": "My Ref 1",
"shippingRef2": "My Ref 2",
"shippingRef3": "My Ref 3",
"customsValue": null,
"deliveryInstructions": "Please deliver with neighbour",
"parcelDescription": "",
"liabilityValue": null,
"liability": false
}]
}';


       // $authentication = base64_encode("USER:PASS");

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,        // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $raw_data,
               // CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,         // follow redirects
               // CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "utf-8",           // handle all encodings
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect
               // CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,          // timeout on connect
               // CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 20,          // timeout on response
                CURLOPT_POST            => 1,            // i am sending post data
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request,    // this are my post vars
               // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,            // don't verify ssl
               // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        //
               // CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
                    "Accept: application/json",
                    "Content-Type: application/json",
                    "GEOClient: account/XX-ACC_NO-XX",
                    "GEOSession: XX-SESS_ID-XX"
                )

        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
        //echo $curl_errno;
        //echo $curl_error;
        print_r($data);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}


$url = "https://api.URL.com";

CurlSendPostRequest($url);

        ?>
```

Comment: is the internal server error their side, or yours? that code runs fine for me, I get "Failed connect to api.URL.com:443" (obviously). No internal server error.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" just means that the browser received response code 500 when it made the HTTP request to your server. The error could have been triggered for a number of reasons; you will need to examine your PHP log to find the specific cause.

Comment: Have you located where the error might be? Can you provide a bit more explanation - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very silly mistake was done : I added a line

```
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $raw_data,
```

and few lines below I added

```
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request,
```

My values for the raw Data are in $raw_data, thus $request was over-writing that.Just need to comment the line :

```
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request,
```

and it works great!